# Version of gcov that supports code coverage for shared library

Tags: gcov

Which version of gcov supports the code-coverage of shared libraries?

Comment: What is the gcov command you are using? What is the linking command?

Answer (score 2):

I am using gcc/gcov 4.1.2 and it works for taking code coverage of shared libraries.

Comment: What is the gcov command you are using? What is the linking command?